# How to imitate focus on a div element?

Tags: jquery, css, focus

The scenario involves imitating a drop down list. Instead of the standard input select element, we're using a set of custom images in combination with a few CSS styles and jQuery behaviors.

All in all, we have a drop down list that works just fine. The question revolves around a drop down list losing focus. A normal select element losing focus would automatically close the list, however, since we are using a set of divs, it's not possibly to set or lose focus(and subsequently hide the list).

We've been able to imitate normal drop down behavior by hiding a text input behind the div and setting the focus to it dynamically. For example:

*User clicks drop down list -> content list is displayed and hidden text input is set as focus.
Event is bound to the text input losing focus which hides the content list.*

I'm curious if the community has a better approach to hiding a div when a user clicks off, presses escape, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could get the desired behavior by wisely using the [jQuery outside events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/).

Comment: Much appreciated. So much cleaner than adding additional elements to the page.